# Copy excel table into DataTable faster

Tags: c#, .net, excel, datatable

I am trying to copy an excel sheet with 1 Million records into a Data Table. Unfortunately it takes about 47 seconds to complete this process. Is there a better way to copy this information over in less time?

Here's the code that ports the info in:

```
String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                            fileName +
                             ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;';";

                        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                        OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From ["           + sheetName + "$]", con);
                        con.Open();

                        OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);

                        dtTemp.Reset();
                        dtTemp.TableName = userUpload;

                        sda.Fill(dtTemp); //Puts imported table into the dtTemp table
                        con.Close();
                        string fields = "";
                        string tempString;

                        foreach (DataColumn col in dtTemp.Columns) //Generates SQL String from imported table
                        {
                            tempString = RemoveSpecialCharacters(col.ColumnName);
                            if (dtTemp.Columns.IndexOf(col) == dtTemp.Columns.Count - 1)
                            {
                                fields += " [" + tempString + "] varchar(255)";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                fields += " [" + tempString + "] varchar(255)" + ",";
                            }

                        }

                        fields = fields.Trim();
                        // createSQLConn(fields, connection, connectionTempDB, dtTemp);
                    }
```

Comment: This code is not complete

Comment: Is dtTemp already bound to a UI object? Is the file local or on the network?

Comment: You should definetly use StringBuilder, not because its faster but this loop will produce lots of strings otherwise.